12 V relay buzzing/fast clicking sound when getting signal from Arduino UNO
I'm new to electronics but I decided I want to try and build a simple circuit to control with my Adruino UNO R3.
I want to make a relay switch on and off programmatically with my UNO.
Here is my current code:
    #define RELAY_PIN 2
    
    void setup() {
      pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
    }

Here is the diagram of my current circuit:

The relay I'm using is a 12 V low level trigger relay (in diagram.)
The problem is when the IN1 wire is connected to pin 2 on the UNO, the relay buzzes consistently and doesn't open/close the circuit, but when I take the IN1 wire and put it into 12V- on the power supply, the relay opens/closes.
I watched a YouTube video where a BC547 transistor was used. I tried it (UNO D2 to base, IN1 to emitter) and no success as well.
How do I get the relay to work correctly?

How is your Arduino powered?  Does it share a ground with your relay board?

You MUST connect the Arduino Ground to the relay board/12 V power supply Ground/Negative so that the Arduino and relay board have a common reference.

@vir the Adruino is powered by the USB cable for now, no ground from Adruino to relay board (not sure where it should go becuase it's a 12v relay board). I was thinking of powering it with the same 12v power supply because the specifications seem to support 12v.

@PeterBennett so my Adruino is powered by the usb port now, is it a problem that the relay board gnd is 12v and the adruino is 5v?

Yeah the voltages aren't necessarily a problem but you need a common ground between the two (and obviously powering the Arduino from the same 12V supply counts as a common ground too). I would be slightly wary of just connecting a random USB ground to a separate power supply, especially if the USB is coming from your computer and not just a power brick.

@vir So I tried connecting the ground of the relay board to the ground of the adruino + 12v power supply and it keeps the relay on the on position, the led light of the relay goes red and brighter red every two seconds (because of the script). Should I rather power the Adruino with the 12v psu so there is a common ground?

You now have a common ground, but it sounds like your "low" output isn't turning the opto on your board off. Could be a config thing on the board. Hard to tell with those undocumented modules that are usually a cheap knockoff of a bad copy of a marginal original design (not a knock on you, just unscrupulous sellers).

@vir It's an official Adruino Uno R3 (as far as I can tell) from a reputable seller. The D2 voltage alternates from 0v to ~4.95v because of the script.

I meant the relay board.

@vir may I ask whats the purpose of the BC547 Transistor? is it to increase the signal voltage to 12v for the relay?

Looks like it but I can't speak for the designers of the board.


You need a ground wire from the Arduino to the relay module. (This has already been mentioned and didn't completely fix the problem.)
Power the relay module from 5V instead of 12V.  The relay have a rated coil voltage of 5V, not 12V and there doesn't appear to be a voltage regulator on the board.

This is how you should wire it using a power supply:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You should be able to wire it this way:

simulate this circuit
That should work if the relay module only requires 5V as I suspect.

If you are really using the pictured power supply, you need to be very careful around it.  There are exposed screw terminals with 220VAC on them.  Touching those screw terminals could kill you.

Do I connect pin Vin on the Uno to the VCC pin on the relay, and then the GND next to Vin on the Uno to the GND of the relay and then the D2 from the Uno to the IN1 on the relay? will this work on 5v from the USB cable?

Thanks for the schematic, just to confirm: which ground on the Uno do I use? the one by the Digital pins or one of ones by the Power pins?

I tried your second circuit and the light on the ralay goes on and off, but the relay isn't clicking

The solution for me was to use a 5v relay module

You need to connect a ground wire from the Arduino to the ground of the relay board in addition to the IN1 wire you already have connected such that they are working from a common ground potential.

do I connect the Digital GND to the GND on the Relay Module and then the IN1 the D2 pin as well as have the VCC to the 12v + of the power supply?

Yes that correct
